# Getting all the Methods from a dll in an array or list

Tags: c#

I'm using reflection to get all the methods from a particular dll that is decorated with a custom attribute. However im not able to get all those methods in an arraylist or a list for it says like this "cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.ICollection'".

The Code is as below

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
 var methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public);
               foreach (var method in type.GetMethods())
                 {
                var attributes = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(model.Class1), true);
                                if (attributes.Length != 0)
                                {

                                    for(int i=0;i<attributes.Length; i++)
                                    {
                                       ArrayList res = new ArrayList();
                                       res.AddRange(method.Name);
                                       listBox1.DataSource = res;
 }                                   }
}
}
```

Comment: Please let me know how do i achieve this..,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is all over the place, I'm afraid.

- You're binding against a new list with a single entry for every attribute in every method, instead of collecting all the method names and then binding once
- You're calling `AddRange` with a single value
- Your `methods` variable is completely unused, and it will be empty anyway as you're neither specifying `Instance` or `Static` binding flags

I would suggest using LINQ for this, and [`MemberInfo.IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.isdefined.aspx), and definitely avoid using `ArrayList`. (Non-generic collections are so 2004...)

```
var methods = type.GetMethods()
                  .Where(method => method.IsDefined(typeof(model.Class1), false)
                  .Select(method => method.Name)
                  .ToList();
listBox1.DataSource = methods;
```

I'd also suggest changing your attribute name from `model.Class1` to something that follows .NET naming conventions and indicates the meaning of the attribute...

Comment: Hi i tried the above linq code but i do not see the listbox displaying any method names here is what i tried...i'm not sure as to what im doing wrong..and also i would take care of the naming conventions and thanks for replying back...

Comment: foreach (MemberInfo mi in type.GetMembers())
                    {
                                               if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Method)
                        {
                            var methods = type.GetMethods().Where(method => method.IsDefined(typeof(model.Class1), false)).Select(method => method.Name).ToList();
                            listBox1.DataSource = methods;
                        }
                    }
                }

Comment: @user2115640: That's not what I suggested, is it? Why have you added a `foreach` loop around it? What diagnostics have you performed to see if `methods` has any elements in it?

Answer (score 1):

Create a generic list instead of an array to store method names.